# error: variable-sized object may not be initialized in c compiler

Tags: c

**error: variable-sized object may not be initialized**

**
the problem is when I put `size` between two  Brackets it gives me an error but when I put `10` its works successfully, also I tried to use `const int size` but it doesn't work.
**

this is the following code  :

```
    int main(){
       int size = 10;
       int array[size]={35,9,41,22,11,80,7,3,6,4};
        for (int d=0;d<size;d++)
        {
          printf ("%d\t\n",array[d]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have to "put `size` between two Brackets"?

Comment: _also i tried to use `const int size` but it doesnt work_ --> `enum{size = 10};` (a real constant) is what you want.